# Align center message materialize css framework

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to implement user notification messages for users but I'm unable to center it. This is how my HTML look like :

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div id="card-alert" class="card green lighten-5">
          <div class="card-content green-text">
            <p>Successfully added a product!</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="close green-text" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

But I'm unable to center the card in the middle of the row. I tried also changing HTML to this :

```
<div class="card-content green-text valign center-block">
  <p>Successfully added a product!</p>
</div>
```

I tried a couple of other things too, but it doesn't work. How would you center this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class `center` if you just wants horizontal alignment.

```
<div class="card-content green-text center">
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div id="card-alert" class="card green lighten-5">
      <div class="card-content green-text center">
        <p>Successfully added a product!</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="close green-text" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And add the following classes for both horizontal and vertical alignment.

```
<div class="card-content green-text center valign-wrapper">
<p class="valign">Successfully added a product!</p>
```

With following styles:

```
.valign-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
}

.valign {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css');

.valign-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
}

.valign {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div id="card-alert" class="card green lighten-5">
      <div class="card-content green-text center valign-wrapper">
        <p class="valign">Successfully added a product!</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="close green-text" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
#card-alert > div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```css
#card-alert > div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m4">
        <div id="card-alert" class="card green lighten-5">
          <div class="card-content green-text">
            <p>Successfully added a product!</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="close green-text" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```